# Window won't receive WM_DPICHANGED message when Set window style to WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW on Windows 11

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi, windows-11

My WPF application DPI awareness is PM2. And I need to set one of my WPF application windows to WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW. When I set it, the window will not receive WM_DPICHANGED message and scale on Windows 11. However it works well on Windows 10.

And there is a demo on [github](https://github.com/imechZhangLY/ToolWindowDPI/tree/main)

There are two windows in this demo, one is normal, and the other was applied WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style by the following code.

```cs
public static int SetToolWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    var extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EX_STYLE);
    return SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EX_STYLE, (extendedStyle | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) & ~WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
}
```

Does anyone have the same trouble? Is it a bug or new feature of Windows 11. And what can I do to let my tool window response to DPI changed event and keep it syle to WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW.

I have tried to remove WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style. It can response to DPI changed event on Win 11. But I need keep my window to be tool window and not shown in the dialog that appears when the user presses ALT+TAB

Comment: Don't have that exact Windows version. I checked on Windows 11 Pro 22H2 - 22621.1928 and WM_DPICHANGED is received.

Comment: Note: With WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style set, on Windows 11, the window will only receive WM_DPICHANGED if you move/resize it after you change the DPI settings. Seems like a bug.

Comment: I just set `WindowStyle="ToolWindow"` in Xaml and found that the same issue happens on Window 11 23H2. I rarely use ToolWindow though.

Comment: You can [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).

Comment: Or if the issue has a big impact on you, please open an incident at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/?tabs=Contact-us and choose the 'Desktop app UI development - Windows management (User32) API and Windows messages' for Windows SDK for this issue. In-addition, if the support engineer determines that the issue is the result of a bug the service request will be a no-charge case and you won't be charged.